# relations of gz topic & rostopic, and how to check the information of a gz topic message type(like: mav_msgs::msgs::CommandMotorSpeed)?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have learned that `gz topics` use almost the same subscribe and publish mechanism with `ros topics`, but what confuses me is, one name(gazebo/command/motor_speed) of two  topics  appears in a project. One is a `ros topic` and the other is a `gz topic`.

I checked the information of the two topics.

The first one has message type of : `mav_msgs/Actuators`.
The latter one has message type of : `mav_msgs::msgs::CommandMotorSpeed`.

-1.   I want to know the difference between gz topics and ros topics, which matters a lot as for things I am learning now.

-2.   How can I check the content of the message type `mav_msgs::msgs::CommandMotorSpeed`(or any other gz topic message types)?

I would be really grateful if one can help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15789/relations-of-gz-topic-&-rostopic,-and-how-to-check-the-information-of-a-gz-topic-message-type(like:-mav_msgs::msgs::commandmotorspeed)?/) by [Yajing Wang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2611/yajing-wang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. they are totally different things, although they share similar mechanism, as you said. There is no relation at all. For ros topics to be populated by gazebo there must be some gazebo plugin running, actually publishing some ROS messages. Otherwise, gazebo will be on its own.
2. `gz topic -e /some/gazebo/topic/name`

---

Originally posted by [eugene-katsevman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3168/eugene-katsevman/) with karma: 163 on 2017-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1